# Format links: hide link into linklabels

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if it possible to format the following text with links:

```
match 1 
1: http://www.google.it  
2: http://www.example.it 
3: http://www.example2.it
   
match2 15:30
1: http://www.google.it
2: http://www.example.it
3: http://www.example2.it
```

into

```
match 1 
 1: LINK1
 2: LINK2
 3: LINK3
       
 match2 15:30
 1: LINK1
 2: LINK2
 3: LINK3
```

I would like maybe to display it in a richtextbox or whatever control.. Just wondering if it's possible to "hide" the real link under a link label. Thanks

Comment: When you say "link label", are you talking about an actual `LinkLabel` control or is that just a general term for a hyperlink anywhere, including in a `RichTextBox`?

Comment: I don't think that you can do what you want with a `RichTextBox`. I don't use that control much at all but, as far as I can tell, you can't add links yourself but, rather, just get it to display a link automatically when it detects a URL. If you change the text, it won't display a link anymore. I could be wrong about that but my reading of the documentation suggests that's the case.

Comment: as you stated Jm, just a general term for a hyperlink anywhere, including in a RichTextBox..Hmm interesting... As you said, i can detect urls but i cant change the text... what if I use html? would the rtb accept the html format? Like i detect all urls and i iust format like [website1]link1[/website1] ? if not, which would be the best way you would use? thanks

Comment: A `RichTextBox` is so-called because it display Rich Text Format (RTF) data. If you want to display HTML then you'd have to use a `WebBrowser` or `WebView2` control.

Comment: oh i see i got it now, so i avoid the rtb control.. would it be possible, if you dont mind, to give me an example of code for webbrowser? Thanks

Comment: See if this works for you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox